# Test for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{\ln n}}$
Does this series converge or diverge?
I've done it this way,using the integral Cauchy test:

[image: series]

So,I also got that it diverges.

Comment: I have edited your problem but I'm not so sure if that's exactly what you mean to ask.

Comment: Yes,that's what I wanted to ask.Thank you.

Comment: You really should tell us what you think, what you have attempted, even if it failed, not just demand an answer, especially for elementary questions like this.

Comment: @tomasz, I agree. That's why I typically only give sketches of proofs. It seems, though, that people who hold askers' hands and sing Kumbaya get the most upvotes.

Comment: I'm sorry,I'm new here.I've just edited it and put my results.

Answer (score 3):

$\ln n = \frac{\log_2 n}{\log_2 e}$ from properties of logarithms. So,

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{\ln n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{- \frac{\log_2 n }{\log_2 e}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-\frac{1}{\log_2 e}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-\ln 2}$

Of course $\ln 2 <1$ therefore our series deverges.

I used this formula:

$\log_a b = \frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $n\ge 1$, then  $2^{\ln n}\lt e^{\ln n}=n$.

Answer (score 1):

This sum is divergent since $2^{\text{log}(n)} = n^{\text{log}(2)}$, where $\text{log}(2) < \text{log}(e) = 1$. Just compare it to the harmonic series.